# Proving Sobolev space on [0,1] is RKHS

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

My aim is to prove that the space: $\mathcal{H}$ = {$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}: f\;is\;absolutely\;continuous,\;f(0)=f(1)=0,\;f'\in L^2[0,1]$} is a reproducing kernel hilbert space.

Now assuming an inner-product given by: $<f,g> = \int_0^1\;f'(t)g'(t)\;dt$, by writing $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\;dt$
I am able to show using cauchy schwartz inequality that  $|f(x)|\leq ||f|| \sqrt{x}$  and hence show that the Point evaluation functional is bounded. However, for completing the proof I have to show that this space is complete (So that it becomes a hilbert space). How do I do this?

Comment: You know the point evaluation functional is continuous, therefore your space is a closed subspace of the Sobolev space $H^1([0,1])=W^{1,2}([0,1])$. Now follow http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232969/space-sobolev-wm-p-complete to infer that $H^1$ is complete, then use the simple fact that a closed subspace of a complete metric space is another complete metric space. (The only thing that might be left to check is that elements of $H^1([0,1])$ are absolutely continuous, but that's a simple application of Holder's inequality and the Lebesgue FTC.)

Comment: Agreed ...... thanks for the solution :) , Sorry for late reply.