# Showing that spaces $C_b^{(1,2)}$ and $W^{(1,2),p}$ are Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

So in essence there are a few propositions in the beginning.

1. For arbitrary $T$ the space $B(T;\mathbb{C})$ is a space of all (real or) complex functions $f: T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with sup norm, and that is Banach space.
2. Definition of $C_b(\Omega; \mathbb{C}) := B(T;\mathbb{C})\cap C(\Omega; \mathbb{C})$, which is also Banach space.

There is a reminder of weak (initial) topology on (real or complex) vector space $V$. Let there be spaces $V_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in A$ and linear operators $A_\alpha : V \rightarrow V_\alpha$. We denote the coarsest topology on set $V$, on which all defined operators are continuous (bounded), by $\tau$. $V$ with $\tau$ becomes vector space. If we use before defined linear operator to define linear operator from $V$ to product space $\Pi_{\alpha\in A} V_\alpha$ then $\tau$ is inverse image of topology inherited from product on image of that linear operator.
If $V_\alpha$ are Hausdorff spaces, for $V$ with $\tau$ to be Hausdorff it is necessary and enough for the following to be valid.
$$ (\forall v \in V \setminus\{0\})(\exists\alpha\in A)A_\alpha v \neq 0.$$
If spaces $V_\alpha$ are complete, and image of $V$ is closed in a product space, then $V$ is complete with $\tau$.

Now using that I have to prove two things.
We have $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d_1+d_2}$ and set multiindex set
$$\mathcal{A}:= \{\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)\in \mathbb{N}^{d_1+d_2} : 2|\alpha_1| + |\alpha_2|\leq2 \}.$$

And the spaces which need to be proven Banach (complete) are space
$$\mathrm{C}_b^{(1,2)}(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):=\left\{u \in \mathrm{C}_b(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):(\forall {\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}) \partial^{{\alpha}} u \in \mathrm{C}_b(\Omega ; \mathbb{C})\right\}.$$
With norm
$$\|u\|:=\sum_{{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}}\left\|\partial^{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} u\right\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}.$$
And space
$$\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):=\left\{u \in \mathrm{L}^p(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):(\forall {\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}) \partial^{{\alpha}} u \in \mathrm{L}^p(\Omega ; \mathbb{C})\right\}.$$
With norm
$$\|u\|_{\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}(\Omega)}:=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}}\left\|\partial^\alpha u\right\|_{\mathrm{L}^p(\Omega)}^p}.$$

Note that definition means that for $\mathrm{C}_b^{(1,2)}(\Omega ; \mathbb{C})$ all first derivations are in $C_b(\Omega; \mathbb{C})$ and second derivations only for indices $x_{d_1+1},...,x_{d_2}$.

$$u_{x_i} \in C_b(\Omega, \mathbf{C}) \quad \text{for $i = 1, 2, ... , d_1, ..., d_2$}$$
$$u_{x_ix_j} \in C_b(\Omega, \mathbf{C}) \quad \text{for $i,j = (d_1 + 1), 2, ... , d_2$}$$

Analogous for the second space.
There is also need to check the details in construction on before-mentioned weak topology.

EDIT:
As far as I can tell, the idea is to take space $C_b$ and linear operators $\partial^{\alpha}$ (in this case derivative in all $\mathbb{R}^{d_1+d_2}$ and second derivative only in the $d_2$ dimensions) to form two spaces whose product space is $C_b^{(1,2)}$ (and analogous for $W^{k,p}$). I am still relatively unsure how.

EDIT 2:
I have found the "connected" question (and answer) in validating the construction of said topology.
[Proof that product topology of subspace is same as induced product topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548495/proof-that-product-topology-of-subspace-is-same-as-induced-product-topology/1548818#1548818)

Comment: Why do you think the proof is different to the standard proofs of completeness for standard $W^{m,p}$ and $C^m$ spaces?

Comment: Oh, it might be the same, but the idea is to use the first part of this not-so-small exercise. That is through linear operators and product space. I have an idea that one should consider linear operators for differentiation and somehow get that the spaces in the exercise are the end product space and conclude from that they are complete, but for now I have no argument for that (though it might be easy my lightbulb is still off).

Comment: You do not need the closedness of the images. Take the proof from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232969/space-sobolev-wm-p-complete Just replace $|\alpha|\le m$ by your condition on the multi-index.

Comment: I mentioned, idea is to use the first part of this exercise, namely "If spaces $V_\alpha$ are complete, and image of $V$ is closed in a product space, then $V$ is complete with $\tau$."