# Does differential operator $D^{\alpha} : W^{m+|\alpha|, p} \rightarrow W^{m, p}$ have a closed image in $W^{m, p}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

I actually have have $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d_1+d_2}$ and set multiindex set
$$\mathcal{A}:= \{\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)\in \mathbb{N}^{d_1+d_2} : 2|\alpha_1| + |\alpha_2|\leq2 \}.$$
And space
$$\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):=\left\{u \in \mathrm{L}^p(\Omega ; \mathbb{C}):(\forall {\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}) \partial^{{\alpha}} u \in \mathrm{L}^p(\Omega ; \mathbb{C})\right\}.$$
With norm
$$\|u\|_{\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}(\Omega)}:=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{{\alpha} \in \mathcal{A}}\left\|\partial^\alpha u\right\|_{\mathrm{L}^p(\Omega)}^p}.$$

I'd like to show that differential operator $D: \mathrm{W}^{1, p} \rightarrow \mathrm{W}^{0, p}$ has a closed image so I can apply that to differential operator from $\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}$ to $\mathrm{W}^{(0,2), p}$.

Note that in general I do not know (yet) if $\mathrm{W}^{(1,2), p}$ is Banach so I am trying to evade solutions that use that fact (with operator being bounded from below).

Comment: Connected https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729408/showing-that-spaces-c-b1-2-and-w1-2-p-are-banach-spaces